# Javascript | Change src to data-attribute active

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I am trying to change the selection of a image based on a data attribute of 'data-active'.

When the data-active is equal to true, then it will change the image to something that indicates that the platform has been selected and all of the others deselect showing only one.

The problem I currently have is that the image is being passed the current platform that is clicked so it is changing the deselected images to the current image clicked on disabled so the images become out of order.

You can see this here... https://miotks.co.uk/register (I have a self assigned certificate)

This is my current code that I have for it...

```
function checkState(obj, platform) {
var checkActive = document.querySelectorAll("[data-active='true']");
var alreadyActive = checkActive.length;

if (alreadyActive >= 2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkActive.length; i++) {

        // Reset the images to the default when all changed to false.
        checkActive[i].setAttribute('data-active', 'false');
        checkActive[i].setAttribute('src', '/images/' + platform + '-noselect.png' );

        obj.setAttribute('data-active', 'true');
        obj.setAttribute('src', '/images/' + platform + '-select.png');
    }
} else {

}}
```

It judges the length of how many elements are selected and have 'true' once this exceeds or is equal to 2, then they all get reset and should change to the current one.

This is how I am calling the function on the click event...

```
checkState(this, 'steam');
```

Comment: That URL returns a 403 error.

Comment: @JLRishe try now, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can just change the `-select` to `-noselect` in each image's url:

```
function checkState(obj, platform) {
    var checkActive = document.querySelectorAll("[data-active='true']");
    var alreadyActive = checkActive.length;

    if (alreadyActive) {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkActive.length; i++) {
            // Reset the images to the default when all changed to false.
            checkActive[i].setAttribute('data-active', 'false');
            checkActive[i].src = checkActive[i].src.replace('-select', '-noselect');
        }
    }

    obj.setAttribute('data-active', 'true');
    obj.src = obj.src.replace('-noselect', '-select');
}
```

Comment: But then when I click on the other images, it doesn't deselect the images that are not currently active.

Comment: @cmiotk If I have understood your question, I believe you want to deselect all images other than the one that was clicked. Am I mistaken?

Comment: That is correct, but using the code that you provided does not achieve this. Instead it just carries on setting the images as the active state rather than the deactivated state

Comment: @cmiotk Please try it again. I have edited it since I originally posted it. I tried it on your site and it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works a charm! I will accept as answer when I can. Do you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: Like I said in the text, it just takes each image's current `.src`, and uses string replacement to replace `-select` with `-noselect` to deselect, or the opposite to select.